# av_free exception when freeing memory, only for this video file

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Other video files I tested will not have problems, only this video file will appear when releasing the pBuffer can not be released, I will post the code to the following
The code for converting the image comes from another open source library libvips, which can be ignored

```
bool TaskThumbnail::videoThmbnail(const QString &video_path, const QString &file_Thumbnail_Cache) {
    bool is_succeeds = false;
    if (!QFile::exists(video_path)) {
        return is_succeeds;
    }
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    AVFormatContext *afc = nullptr;
    struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx = nullptr;
    std::string str_input_file = video_path.toStdString();
    auto ret = avformat_open_input(&afc, str_input_file.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        qDebug() << "opem file fail: " << str_input_file.c_str();
        return is_succeeds;
    }
    int video_stream_idx = -1;
    ret = avformat_find_stream_info(afc, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        qDebug() << "Couldn't find stream information: " << str_input_file.c_str();
        return is_succeeds;
    }
    ret = av_find_best_stream(afc, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, NULL, 0);
    video_stream_idx = ret >= 0 ? ret : -1;
    if (video_stream_idx != -1) {
        auto av_code_par = afc->streams[video_stream_idx]->codecpar;
        if (av_code_par) {
            auto codec = avcodec_find_decoder(av_code_par->codec_id);
            if (codec) {
                auto avcodectx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
                AVFrame *pFrameDec = NULL;
                AVFrame *pFrameRGB = NULL;
                pFrameDec = av_frame_alloc();
                pFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc();
                int numBytes = 0;
                uint8_t *pBuffer = nullptr;
                AVPacket *packet = nullptr;
                packet = av_packet_alloc();
                int width = av_code_par->width;
                int height = av_code_par->height;
                av_new_packet(packet, width * height); //调整packet的数据
                if (avcodectx) {
                    if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(avcodectx, av_code_par) >= 0) {
                        //打开解码器
                        if (avcodec_open2(avcodectx, codec, NULL) == 0) {
                            while (av_read_frame(afc, packet) >= 0) {
                                //只处理视频帧
                                if (packet->stream_index == video_stream_idx) {
                                    ret = avcodec_send_packet(avcodectx, packet);
                                    if (ret == 0) {
                                        if (avcodec_receive_frame(avcodectx, pFrameDec) == 0) {
                                            //判断是否是关键帧
                                            if (pFrameDec->key_frame) {
                                                numBytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, width, height, 1);
                                                pBuffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes);
                                                // 将图像原始格式转换为RGB格式
                                                img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(
                                                                      width, height, (AVPixelFormat)av_code_par->format,
                                                                      width, height,
                                                                      AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                                                if (!img_convert_ctx) {
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                av_image_fill_arrays(pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize, pBuffer, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, width, height, 1);
                                                sws_scale(img_convert_ctx, pFrameDec->data, pFrameDec->linesize, 0, av_code_par->height, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
                                                //使用vips 生成为jpeg格式图片输出
                                                auto image = vips_image_new_from_memory_copy(pBuffer, numBytes, width, height, 3, VIPS_FORMAT_UCHAR);
                                                if (image) {
                                                    VipsImage *outImage = nullptr;
                                                    auto res = vips_thumbnail_image(image, &outImage, 480, "height", 270, "size", VIPS_SIZE_DOWN, NULL, nullptr);
                                                    if (!outImage || res) {
                                                        auto vips_error_message = vips_error_buffer_copy();
                                                        if (vips_error_message) {
                                                            qDebug() << "errors save thumbnails: " << vips_error_message << " file: " << video_path;
                                                            vips_error_clear();
                                                        }
                                                    } else {
                                                        if (!vips_jpegsave(outImage, file_Thumbnail_Cache.toStdString().c_str(), NULL, nullptr)) {
                                                            is_succeeds = true;
                                                        } else {
                                                            auto vips_error_message = vips_error_buffer_copy();
                                                            if (vips_error_message) {
                                                                qDebug() << "errors save thumbnails: " << vips_error_message << " file: " << video_path;
                                                                vips_error_clear();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        g_object_unref(outImage);
                                                    }
                                                    g_object_unref(image);
                                                }
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                av_packet_unref(packet);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    av_packet_free(&packet);
                    if (pFrameRGB) {
                        av_frame_free(&pFrameRGB);
                    }
                    if (pFrameDec) {
                        av_frame_free(&pFrameDec);
                    }
                    if (pBuffer) {
                        av_free(pBuffer);
                    }
                    if (img_convert_ctx) {
                        sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);
                        img_convert_ctx = nullptr;
                    }
                    avcodec_close(avcodectx);
                    avcodec_free_context(&avcodectx);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //! 关闭格式上下文环境
    avformat_close_input(&afc);
    return is_succeeds;
}
```

I also uploaded the video file here
I put this video file on github because I don't know how to upload video files on stackoverflow
https://github.com/cool2528/minizip/releases/download/1.0.2/20832223.mp4

I hope you can help me to see if there is something wrong with my code or if it is really a problem with this video file. I am confused because I tested all the other video files and this code worked fine except for this video file which failed to free the memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
 numBytes = av_image_get_buffer_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, width, height, 1) * 2;
 pBuffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes);
```

After continuous debugging, we found that the memory requested by pBuffer is too small
You need to change the place where pBuffer requests memory and multiply it by 2 to solve the problem.